# Exhaust fan outlet broken

Tags: exhaust-fan

Can anyone tell me if I can buy an outlet for my bathroom exhaust fan? It cracked and I want to replace. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean *electrical* outlet? Or exhaust fan ductwork outlet for the air?

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the broken thing?

Answer (score 0):

Some older bathroom exhaust fans came equipped with an electrical outlet inside its enclosure where a very short cord from the fan motor would be plugged. These were designed for some installations where a single switch in a bathroom would control both a light and the fan. Sometimes it would be desirable to disable the fan by removing the grate and unplugging the fan motor. *(Some use cases: Quite needed for new baby in house - Extreme weather conditions - Clogged vent due to snow).* Some models may still be made like this.

If the broken outlet in your fan is this type the best suggestion is to do a search and find the manufacturer telephone support number and call them up. Make sure to have your model number and serial number if applicable. It may take some tenacity to make it through the entry level support personnel at the company but many reputable manufacturers will offer to sell or provide free replacement parts. I've had this happen multiple times including for space heater range selector switches, refrigerator fan blade and chest freezer door hinges being sent for FREE. Key is to be polite, honest and non-demanding.